How to math.sqrt(-1) in python?
math.sqrt() work for int and float and it cant work with a number <0, how can i math.sqrt(-1) ?
#n was -1
def chinhphuong(n):
    if math.sqrt(n).is_integer():
        return True
    return False

this gives ValueError: math domain error

Are you looking for cmath? import cmath; cmath.sqrt(-1) shows 1j.

Right.  math.sqrt works for real numbers.  In the real domain, sqrt(-1) does not exist.

Note that complex numbers (e.g. ones with an imaginary component) are by definition not integers, so there's no math required: just add an if n < 0: return False before the math.sqrt check.


How to math.sqrt(-1) in python?

The square root of minus one is a complex number; see

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imaginary_number
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number

I'm not going to explain to you what imaginary and complex numbers are.  This is something that is normally part of the high-school mathematics syllabus.  If the above links are too hard to understand, I suggest that you Google for simpler explanations.
A complex number cannot be represented by a Python integer or floating point number.  It is represented by the complex type.
If you want to do computations involving complex numbers in Python, the simple way is to use the cmath package; see https://docs.python.org/3/library/cmath.html
For example:
import cmath

print(cmath.sqrt(-1))


For the record, the reason that the test
if math.sqrt(n).is_integer():

in your code doesn't work is that sqrt(n) is throwing an exception before you can test for a non-integer.   It is not returning any value (or None) that can be tested using is_integer().
If you simply want to avoid the ValueError exception, you should rewrite your function as:
def chinhphuong1(n):
    return False if n < 0 else True

Alternatively catch the exception:
def chinhphuong2(n):
   try:
       return math.sqrt(n).is_integer()
   except ValueError:
       return False
   


why not simply try: return math.sqrt(n).is_integer()

@Onyambu If n < 0, it will throw an exception because sqrt(n) will give an imaginary number. Python's math module provides access to real numbers functionality

Well yea ... that would work.  But (IMO) throwing and catching an exception when you can simply test n is a bad idea.

Based on what you're trying to achieve, you should not be using complex number computations at all (and the implementation you have doesn't work with complex numbers; builtins.complex has no method is_integer).
I'm assuming you're using Python >= 3.12, because that's when builtins.int.is_integer actually started existing:
import math

def is_perfect_square(n: float) -> bool:
    if n < 0:
        return False
    return math.sqrt(n).is_integer()

Even if you can't actually control your inputs, and you're actually dealing with complex numbers, you still don't need any computation for complex or negative numbers:
import math

def is_perfect_square(n: complex | float, /) -> bool:
    if isinstance(n, complex):
        if n.imag != 0:
            return False
        n = n.real
    if n < 0:
        return False
    return math.sqrt(n).is_integer()

